# What is everyone's job in Lost in Space?

Tags: lost-in-space-2018

At one point in episode 3 it's mentioned that everyone in the family has a job.  An engineer, a soldier, and a couple of other occupations.  I know the mom is the engineer and the dad is the soldier, but I am unclear as to what jobs the kids are supposed to have.

What is everyone's job in Lost In Space?

Answer (score 3):

While only Judy's job is well defined (physician), the show appears to infer qualities / specialisms in the other 2 children. Both are there because they (appear) to have passed both the physical and technical stress tests like everyone on the expedition, but it appears that Will is extremely knowledgeable in the areas of geology and geochemistry (and uses it to save lives from the get go) while Penny appears to represent one of the many artisans that would be welcomed on a new colony in order to preserve and continue human culture (she is extremely literate and appears to have studied the forms as well as being an aspiring writer / poet herself.)